# Isometric manifolds can be mapped by a motion?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, isometry

Does the following result hold ?

Let $M$ and $N$ two smooth submanifolds of $(\mathbb R^n, g_{\mathrm{can}})$ such that $M$ and $N$ are isometric as smooth Riemannian manifolds. Then there exists an isometry $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ such that $f(M)=N$.

Comment: In a word, no. (The simplest case is arguably the most extreme: Any two simple, closed plane curves of the same length are globally isometric as Riemannian manifolds. But it's not true in higher dimensions either.)